# Vim Plugins Do Not Load

Tags: vim, plugins

I have tried using vim-plug, pathogen, and now the default Vim 8+ package manager. Nothing I do will load these plugins.

Currently I have a directory in ~/.vim/pack/plugs/start/[where-i-clone-plugins]

Is something in my .vimrc conflicting with package loading? I have a .vimrc in ~/

```
" vim configuration file
  
" use Vim mode instead of pure Vi, it must be the first instruction
set nocompatible

" display settings
set encoding=utf-8 " encoding used for displaying file
set ruler " show the cursor position all the time
set showmatch " highlight matching braces
set showmode " show insert/replace/visual mode

" edit settings
set backspace=indent,eol,start " backspacing over everything in insert mode
set nojoinspaces " no extra space after '.' when joining lines
set shiftwidth=4 " set indentation depth to 4 columns
set softtabstop=4 " backspacing over 4 spaces like over tabs
set tabstop=4 " set tabulator length to 4 columns
set textwidth=80 " wrap lines automatically at 80th column

"search settings
set hlsearch " highlight search results
set ignorecase " do case insensitive search...

"file type specific settings
filetype on " enable file type detection
filetype indent on " automatically indent code


set background=dark " dark background for console
syntax enable " enable syntax highlighting
```

:version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Nov 08 2021 14:21:34)
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +cursorbind        +insert_expand     +mouse_sgr         -ruby              +title
+arabic            +cursorshape       +job               -mouse_sysmouse    +scrollbind        -toolbar
+autocmd           +dialog_con        +jumplist          +mouse_urxvt       +signs             +user_commands
+autochdir         +diff              +keymap            +mouse_xterm       +smartindent       +vartabs
-autoservername    +digraphs          +lambda            +multi_byte        +sound             +vertsplit
-balloon_eval      -dnd               +langmap           +multi_lang        +spell             +virtualedit
+balloon_eval_term -ebcdic            +libcall           -mzscheme          +startuptime       +visual
-browse            +emacs_tags        +linebreak         +netbeans_intg     +statusline        +visualextra
++builtin_terms    +eval              +lispindent        +num64             -sun_workshop      +viminfo
+byte_offset       +ex_extra          +listcmds          +packages          +syntax            +vreplace
+channel           +extra_search      +localmap          +path_extra        +tag_binary        +wildignore
+cindent           -farsi             -lua               -perl              -tag_old_static    +wildmenu
-clientserver      +file_in_path      +menu              +persistent_undo   -tag_any_white     +windows
-clipboard         +find_in_path      +mksession         +postscript        -tcl               +writebackup
+cmdline_compl     +float             +modify_fname      +printer           +termguicolors     -X11
+cmdline_hist      +folding           +mouse             +profile           +terminal          -xfontset
+cmdline_info      -footer            -mouseshape        -python            +terminfo          -xim
+comments          +fork()            +mouse_dec         +python3           +termresponse      -xpm
+conceal           +gettext           +mouse_gpm         +quickfix          +textobjects       -xsmp
+cryptv            -hangul_input      -mouse_jsbterm     +reltime           +textprop          -xterm_clipboard
+cscope            +iconv             +mouse_netterm     +rightleft         +timers            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-BPbmc6/vim-8.1.226
tack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lsel
lcanberra -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -
```

Comment: 1. Can we see the full output of `:version`? 2. Are you using Vim as you or as root?

Comment: @romainl Not using as root. Updated with :version

Comment: Your Vim apparently has what it takes and the path you gave in the question is correct. This is rather puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fix. Workaround was to just load my colorscheme plugin as a colorscheme either in ~/.vim/colors or /usr/share/vim/vim81/colors.

vim-plug wasn't working but I got the other couple plugins I wanted working with Pathogen.